# Python extract substring from between parenthesis

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a string, that is formatted like that:

`"Name Surname (ID), Name2 Surname2 (ID2)"`

ID starts with letter that is followed by few digits. We can have various number of people in that string (I mean there can be only one person, 2 as in provided example or even more). Also, people can have few names or surnames, so it's not consistent.

I want to extract a substring built of ID's divided by colons, so for this example it would look like that:

`"ID, ID2"`

Right now i tried this approach:

```py
import re

string = "Bob Rob Smith (L1234567), John Doe (k12345678)"
result = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z][0-9]+', string)
','.join(result)
```

And it works perfectly fine, but I wonder if there's simpler approach that doesn't require any additional modules. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: What's your actual objective in trying to avoid standard library modules?

Comment: You could split on `),` and take the last 8 characters from each element in the split list but regex is the correct approach

Comment: I was just wondering if my approach is correct or if there's simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think using `re` is good approach, if you have to NOT use `re` AT ANY PRICE, then you might do:

```
s = "Bob Rob Smith (L1234567), John Doe (k12345678)"
result = s.replace(')','(').split('(')[1::2]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['L1234567', 'k12345678']
```

Explanation: I want to split at `(` and `)`, but `.split` method of `str` accepts only one delimiter, so I firstly replace `)` with `(`, then I split and get odd elements. This method will work if: `(` and `)` are used solely around `ID`s, `s` does not starts with `(`, `s` does not starts with `)`, there is at least one character between any two brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on `),` and take the last 8 characters from each element in the split list but regex is the correct approach

```
 [s[-8:] for s in mystring[:-1].split('),')]
```

Answer (score 0):

to me, the `RegEx` approach seems the best approach.

Assuming that you do not know exactly how many digits your IDs have (quote: *followed by a few digits*), you could through the whole string and catch what's inside parenthesis:

```
s = "Bob Rob Smith (L1234567), John Doe (k12345678)"

res = []
word = ''
open = False
for x in s:
    if x == '(':
        open = True
        continue
    if x == ')':
        open = False
        res.append(word)
        word = ''
    if open:
        word += x

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ['L1234567', 'k12345678']